# Azure Web App URL Rewrite not working

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to get a basic URL rewrite to work for my Azure web App

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SalesCloudGmail" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/SalesCloudGmail.aspx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/SalesCloudGmail" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Was expecting to open the URL .../SalesCloudGmail.aspx  and see .../SalesCloudGmail in the Address bar???

What Am I missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, your regex pattern matching is a little off based on how you're using it. But this should work or at least get you much closer.

```
<rule name="SalesCloudGmail" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^\/SalesCloudGmail\.aspx.*" />
         </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/SalesCloudGmail" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: Thanks - that rewrote the url...  now it can't find the resource (Error = The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.)  I must have misunderstood the functionality - thought it would still display the page just with a modified address url?

Comment: If you're looking to just rewrite the URL and not `Redirect`, you need to change the action type to `Rewrite`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below rewrite rule:

```html
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="SalesCloudGmail" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^\/SalesCloudGmail\.aspx$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="/SalesCloudGmail" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Please following [this article](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns) to test your match pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Jambor - same issue.  URL is unchanged when I open it. http://cloudtrio.com/SalesCloudGmail.aspx